# Error: “no access to library BloggerApp” when calling GmailApp object in Google Apps Script

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

“You do not have access to library BloggerApp, used by your script, or it has been deleted.”

Google Apps Script throws the above error when I run the following code:

```
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // get first thread in inbox
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // get first message
Logger.log(message.getBody()); // log contents of the body
```

I have isolated the problem to the GmailApp object call by testing the following subset of the above code (which produces the same error):

```
var thread = GmailApp;
```

Solution attempts tried & failed:

1. I signed up for a Blogger account. (No impact.)
2. I searched under the “manage libraries...” menu for “BloggerApp” (No results returned.)
3. I attempted to publish my script as a service and add my script to my library. (This solution did not make logical sense to me at the time but I tried it anyway because I was running out of ideas.)
4. I did a google search and a Stack Overflow search and found no similar issues anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been resolved. The problem was caused by the unsuccessful attempt to add a 3rd-party script library into my script.

Comment: Can you tell us anything more about that 3rd party script?  I'm trying to access Blogger from google app scripts and would love to use an existing BloggerApp ...