# BloggerApp for Google App Scripts

Tags: api, google-apps-script, blogger

I'm trying to connect to Blogger from Google App Scripts, and it seems like I can go through UrlFetchApp to hit the Blogger API directly and start parsing XML etc., however I wonder if there is already a BloggerApp that would save me the trouble.  I see it mentioned in this post:

[Error: “no access to library BloggerApp” when calling GmailApp object in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230538/error-no-access-to-library-bloggerapp-when-calling-gmailapp-object-in-google)

but I can't find any other reference to it.  I guess I might get -1'd again because here I am asking about the existence of a library before I've tried to write the entire thing myself, however given that I will probably do a hacky job of it, it really does seem sensible and expedient to ask here first - particularly since the Google App Scripts folk don't host their own forum and direct all questions to be asked here.

Naturally if BloggerApp doesn't exist I'll write my own and then post it here ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a Blogger library for Apps Script. You'll have to write one yourselves.

You can use the [Picasa sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/picasa_google_apis) and change it to use the [Blogger GData APIs](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol).

If you don't need OAuth or if you can write your own OAuth2 (as Apps Script only supports OAuth1), you can use the newer [Blogger v3 API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using).

Comment: update: Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported.